# How to use ` in question

Tags: support, questions, code-formatting

I asked a question on SO today and added stack trace along with the question, so the stack trace contained character **`** in between. As we know this is used for the inline code on SO. But at that time it was not intended for the code but was part of stack trace.

So my question is, is there any way to escape this character on SO?

Comment: Yes, escape with a backslash.  \`

Comment: A stack trace is best indented as a code block, where a backtick has no special meaning.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I prefer a `<pre>`. That way it doesn't turn into a colouring book from the system's attempt at syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Stijn: I prefer using `<!-- language: lang-none -->` if syntax highlighting is really a problem for the traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's what I always use, `lang-none`. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you post your stacktrace as a code block the backticks will be preserved. They are not special characters in code blocks.

```
stacktrace example foo ` bar ` foobar
```

Comment: stacktrace was wrapped in quote block, ryanyuyu and Martjin Pieters solution works fine.